# What is the pre requisite to be able to use Unix's rlogin command?

Tags: unix

What is the pre requisite to be able to use Unix's rlogin command?

Regards
Chaitanya

Comment: Please state which version of Unix you are asking about. I can remove the -1 if you do this, as I answered the question for Mac OS X which uses Unix as its underlying OS. I'm sorry though I should have informed you that Mac OS X was Unix when I posted the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See here: http://docs.hp.com/en/B2355-90164/ch06s05.html

Answer (score -1):

In Mac OS X under the "Sharing" category in "System preferences" you need to enable "Remote Login" by clicking the checkbox.

Comment: Hi Zubair, I clearly mentioned in my question that I need it in Unix.

Comment: yes, your right, I thought you meant Mac OS X Unix. Which version do you mean?

Comment: I would also recommend you edit the question to state that you were specifically looking to know the answer for "HP Unix"